# In GridView,item width and height is code control,but ImageView for first item no response OnClickListener

Tags: android, gridview

This is my use adapter,when I click first item‘s `headImageView`, I don't skip  `OtherUserActivity`, I click second item’s `headImageView`, open many `OtherUserActivity`。I remove `LayoutParams`,click normal

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LoopDetailsDataList loopDetailsDataList = list.get(position);

    ViewHolder holder = ViewHolder.get(context, convertView, parent, R.layout.item_loop_details, position);
    convertView = holder.getConvertView();

    int itemParams = screenWidth / 2 - Utils.newInstance(context).dip2px(10);
    AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(itemParams, itemParams);
    convertView.setLayoutParams(params);

    ImageView mainImageView = holder.getView(R.id.item_loop_details_image);
    CircleImageView headImageView = holder.getView(R.id.item_loop_details_head_image);

    TextView userName = holder.getView(R.id.item_loop_details_user_name);
    TextView title = holder.getView(R.id.item_loop_details_title);
    TextView praise = holder.getView(R.id.item_loop_details_praise);
    TextView comments = holder.getView(R.id.item_loop_details_comments);

    headImageView.setTag(position);
    headImageView.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(position));

    return convertView;
}

private class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int index;

    private MyClickListener(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String userSign = list.get(index).getaCreateUserSign();
        Log.i(TAG, "CreateUserSign:" + userSign);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtherUserActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userSign", userSign);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

this is my ViewHolder

```
private ViewHolder(Context context, ViewGroup parent, int layoutId,
                   int position) {
    this.mPosition = position;
    this.mViews = new SparseArray<>();
    mConvertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
    // setTag
    mConvertView.setTag(this);
}

public static ViewHolder get(Context context, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, int layoutId, int position) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder(context, parent, layoutId, position);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.mPosition = position;
    }
    return holder;
}

public View getConvertView() {
    return mConvertView;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends View> T getView(int viewId) {
    View view = mViews.get(viewId);
    if (view == null) {
        view = mConvertView.findViewById(viewId);
        mViews.put(viewId, view);
    }
    return (T) view;
}

public ViewHolder setText(int viewId, String text) {
    TextView view = getView(viewId);
    view.setText(text);
    return this;
}

public ViewHolder setImageResource(int viewId, int drawableId) {
    ImageView view = getView(viewId);
    view.setImageResource(drawableId);

    return this;
}


public ViewHolder setImageBitmap(int viewId, Bitmap bm) {
    ImageView view = getView(viewId);
    view.setImageBitmap(bm);
    return this;
}

public ViewHolder setImageByUrl(int viewId, String url) {
    ImageLoaderUtils.getInstance(3, ImageLoaderUtils.Type.LIFO).loadImage(url,
            (ImageView) getView(viewId));
    return this;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting layout Paramus of the convertview after passing it to the holder

Comment: i hope item widht and height adapt phone screen

Comment: Ok you can achieve that by just adding (match_parent) for the layout_width in your R.layout.item_loop_details

Comment: my GridView numColumns is 2,if i don't use LayoutParams,item style isn't my hope

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that.

Comment: So when you click on the first item's image nothing happens, but it works on the second item. Is that correct??

Comment: yes.  not only that,open more OtherUserActivity

Comment: That's really weird, It seems that its responding to all the listeners at once

Comment: Can you show the viewholder code??

Comment: I can't understand it,other people say there may be a click on the interception of events

Comment: i add ViewHolder code

Comment: can you add in the Log.i(TAG, "CreateUserSign:" + userSign+" For Index"+index); to check if you are getting the right indexes

Answer (score 0):

Well you shouldn't change the *width* of your view to half the screen because if you are using a `gridview` it will take care of that for you if you specify the the number of columns or it will set it to its default ***2*** columns. I think that there are some overlapping views due to resizing, so hopefully that will solve it. 
Also you should do two other things to your code:

**First** you need to put `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`out side the `if else` because you do it no matter what, thats for convention sake.

**Second** you are not setting the `mConvertView` in your `holder` get method in the else block.

Comment: I'm sorry to return to you now.I use other customView solved the problem,Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yeah glad to hear that, thanks. What `customview` did you use? also here is an amazing library for `gridviews` https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Comment: I use StaggeredGridView (https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid),this is a Waterfall flow,extends AbsListView,i control item width and height, realized my effect. i'm add refresh,use android-pulltorefresh (https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)

Comment: I think RecyclerView load a great many data,sliding will appear problem